# SSIS Constraints

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

We have containers(steps) which only run on Wednesdays.  I want SSIS/VS to wait until that has been evaluated before proceeding.
Please see this picture for an example:
[image: Example SSIS Package]

In the example, Pass_3 only runs on Wednesdays.  I want Pass_Final to wait, until Pass_3 is evaluated and either runs with Success or doesn't run.  If either of those occur, go to Pass_Final.  But, if Pass_3 runs and fails, don't proceed to Pass_Final.  The way it is currently, if Pass_3 doesn't run, Pass_Final will not run.

Is this possible?
Visual Studio 2015/SSDT 2015

Comment: Where does Pass_4 come into play?    Whether or not Pass_Final is executed or not would be dependent on the completion of Pass_4 and or Pass_3 depending on how you configured the "Precedence Constraint" between Pass_Final and one of the other steps.  Double click the green arrow between pass_4 and Final_pass, towards the bottom under "Mulitple Constraints", AND would be both need to succeed, OR would be one or the other.

Comment: Your question isn't quite complete.   What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: @TabAlleman, sorry about that, I edited the question.  The current issue is Pass_Final will not run if Pass_3 does not run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be easier to follow, I'm sure, if I provided an image, but right now I only have time to type.  Hopefully this will be clear enough.

What you need to do is to re-work the `pass_3` path so that it returns true when it's not Wednesday.

One way to do that is to add a dummy script task that doesn't do anything between `pass_3` and `pass_final`.   So you will have completion constraints going from `pass_3` to `dummy_task` and also from `dummy_task` to `pass_final`.

THEN you add a constraint from `pass_1` straight to `dummy_task` that checks to see if the day is NOT Wednesday.  And use an OR condition on the constraints going to `dummy_task` so that only one of them has to be true.

What this does is, on Wednesday, `pass_3` will be used, and when completed, it will activate `dummy_task` which will pass through to `pass_final`, and every other day, `pass_3` will be skipped, but `dummy_task` will still get activated and pass through to `pass_final`.

hope this is clear enough.

Comment: I'll do some more testing, but I think that will work for me.  Thanks.